# Hide LaodingView when search have no result

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-paging

I have implemented search functionality in my app which display result as a verticalGridView with pagination : https://github.com/alirezaeiii/TMDb-Compose

I have following logic for refresh load state that works as I wish :

```
@Composable
fun <T : TMDbItem> PagingScreen(
    viewModel: BasePagingViewModel<T>,
    onClick: (TMDbItem) -> Unit,
) {
    val lazyTMDbItems = viewModel.pagingDataFlow.collectAsLazyPagingItems()

    when (lazyTMDbItems.loadState.refresh) {
        is LoadState.Loading -> {
            TMDbProgressBar()
        }
        is LoadState.Error -> {
            val message =
                (lazyTMDbItems.loadState.refresh as? LoadState.Error)?.error?.message ?: return

            lazyTMDbItems.apply {
                ErrorScreen(
                    message = message,
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    refresh = { retry() }
                )
            }
        }
        else -> {
            LazyTMDbItemGrid(lazyTMDbItems, onClick)
        }
    }
}
```

In LazyTMDbItemGrid, I try to manage append load state as follow :

```
@Composable
private fun <T : TMDbItem> LazyTMDbItemGrid(
    lazyTMDbItems: LazyPagingItems<T>,
    onClick: (TMDbItem) -> Unit,
) {
    LazyVerticalGrid(
        columns = GridCells.Fixed(COLUMN_COUNT),
        contentPadding = PaddingValues(
            start = Dimens.GridSpacing,
            end = Dimens.GridSpacing,
            bottom = WindowInsets.navigationBars.getBottom(LocalDensity.current)
                .toDp().dp.plus(
                    Dimens.GridSpacing
                )
        ),
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(
            Dimens.GridSpacing,
            Alignment.CenterHorizontally
        ),
        content = {

            repeat(COLUMN_COUNT) {
                item {
                    Spacer(
                        Modifier.windowInsetsTopHeight(
                            WindowInsets.statusBars.add(WindowInsets(top = 56.dp))
                        )
                    )
                }
            }

            items(lazyTMDbItems.itemCount) { index ->
                val tmdbItem = lazyTMDbItems[index]
                tmdbItem?.let {
                    TMDbItemContent(
                        it,
                        Modifier
                            .height(320.dp)
                            .padding(vertical = Dimens.GridSpacing),
                        onClick
                    )
                }
            }

            lazyTMDbItems.apply {
                when (loadState.append) {
                    is LoadState.Loading -> {
                        item(span = span) {
                            LoadingRow(modifier = Modifier.padding(vertical = Dimens.GridSpacing))
                        }
                    }
                    is LoadState.Error -> {
                        val message =
                            (loadState.append as? LoadState.Error)?.error?.message ?: return@apply

                        item(span = span) {
                            ErrorScreen(
                                message = message,
                                modifier = Modifier.padding(vertical = Dimens.GridSpacing),
                                refresh = { retry() })
                        }
                    }
                    else -> {}
                }
            }
        })
}
```

The problem is when there is no result for search, or when result items is shorter than screen size, it displays LoadingRow. My expectation is when we are in this state, LoadingRow does not display, but how can I detect this state?

Comment: You can pass the state down to your LoadingRow and then use that to either show/hide that element. I have done something similar and you can check it out [here](https://github.com/TomerPacific/movies-presenter/blob/main/app/src/main/java/com/tomerpacific/moviepresenter/ui/view/CircularProgressBarIndicator.kt).

Comment: I understand, but the question is when to pass in the LaodingRow. In your case you do not have pagination, but I check for LoadState.Loading when state is append.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct me if I'm wrong but these should be dictated by the `PagingSource.LoadResult.Page`

Documentation :

> Success result object for PagingSource.load. Params: data - Loaded
> data prevKey - Key for previous page if more data can be loaded in
> that direction, null otherwise. nextKey - Key for next page if more
> data can be loaded in that direction, null otherwise.

So if you reached the pagination end (in either direction) :

```
PagingSource.LoadResult.Page(
        data = loadedData,
        prevKey = null,
        nextKey = null)
```

Comment: Exactly I missed to set null for nextKey when there is no item. So I fixed it by 
nextKey = if (response.isEmpty()) null else page + 1